# Retrieve HasUniqueRoleAssigments value from a List Item in a SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I'm trying to  retrieve the value of 'HasUniqueRoleAssignements' from a list item in a SharePoint 2013 Designer workflow.

My request url is:

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/getbytitle('[%Worklfow Context:List Name%]')/items([%CurrentItem:ID%])?$select=HasUniqueRoleAssignements
```

I'm retrieving the response as JSON via a request header which is a dictionary variable built with

```
Accept string application/json;odata=verbose
content-type string application/json;odata=verbose
```

I am getting a response with one item into a dictionary variable but when I try to retrieve the value into a boolean variable with:

```
Get HasUniqueRoleAssignments from variable: JSONResponse (Output to variable: uniqueRoleAssignments)
```

I'm always getting false, even when it should be true.

When I enter the request URL into the browser I can see

```
<d:HasUniqueRoleAssignments m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:HasUniqueRoleAssignments>
```

in the xml response.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Instead of using the request header, which by the way works for different web service calls in the same workflow, I add '$format=json' to the query string

```
[%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/_api/lists/getbytitle('[%Worklfow Context:List Name%]')/items([%CurrentItem:ID%])?$format=json&$select=HasUniqueRoleAssignements
```